# heat equation on a surface

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Probably I have not well understood the heat equation: please, can you confirm or correct the followings ? (The question raised in this post is similar to [Heat Equation on Manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046370/heat-equation-on-manifold) but they don't fully overlap , I hope.)

Consider an homogeneous, isolated, flat disk, having radius $R$, whose center lies on the origin of the Cartesian coordinate, in the plane. At $t=0$ the thermal field is known: $\phi_0(x,y)=\Phi(x,y)$.

To compute $\phi=\phi_t(x,y)$ for $t>0$ we must solve the equation
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} - \alpha  \left(\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}\right)=0$$
Now, instead of the disk, consider a surface, having equation
$$\sigma : (x,y) \rightarrow (x\,,\,y\,,\,z(x,y))$$
Again the initial thermal field is given, but this time the equation 
to solve is
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} -\alpha\frac{1}{h_1h_2h_3}\sum_{i=1}^{3} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg(\frac{h_{a}h_{b}}{h_i}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^i}\bigg)$$
where for $i=1$, we have $a=2$ and $b=3$ etc. cyclically.
That's because the Laplacian operator is written in its most general form.
In inhomogeneous bodies, $\alpha=\alpha(x,y,z)$.

Comment: What's your question? Yes, this sounds like the heat equation... The only thing I question is the definition for your scale factor $h_{p}^{2}=|\frac{\partial\,\sigma}{\partial\, x_p}|$. The definition I'm familiar with involves the *sum* of squares of derivatives... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScaleFactor.html

Comment: My question is, essentially, if I have operated rigthly revriting the equation simply changing the laplacian operator's form or, on the contrary, more subtleties are involved. Do you think I should edit the question ? I have removed the part concerning the scale factors.

Comment: It looks correct, assuming there are no heat sources within the surface. You might find the first pages of the following link useful: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-303-linear-partial-differential-equations-fall-2006/lecture-notes/pde3d.pdf